# exponential equation find exponent value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

**Question:** If               $L \times T^{-2} = L^{n+m} \times T^{-m}$
            Solve for m , n?

**solving for m:**

$-2=-m$      (how???)

$m=2$

**solving for n:**

$n+m=1$      (how???)

$n+2=1$

$n=1-2=-1$

my question is how can we forget about the two L's and just say that $T^{-2}=T^{-m} $

and do the same again this time with the L and ignore the T and say that $L=L^{n+m}$?

Comment: It seems that they made a comparison of the exponents. Additional context is helpful.

Comment: What are L and T?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC L & T stand for length and time, It's just an equtation to calculate the acceleration of a body , where acceleration is how much speed change in time or $\frac{speed}{time}$ or $\frac{length}{\frac{time}{time}} $ , or $Length \times Time^{-2}$

Comment: @technotux Good luck.

Comment: You need to clarify which variables are fixed, and whether this equation holds true for all values or for only certain values of which variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given that
$$
L^1 \times T^{-2} = L^{n + m} \times T^{-m} \tag{1}
$$
where $L$ and $T$ stand for length and time, respectively.

Equating the like exponents in (1), we get
$$
n + m = 1 \tag{2}
$$
and
$$
-m = -2 \tag{3}
$$

From (3), $m = 2$.

Substituting the value of $m$ into (2), we get
$$
n = 1 - 2 = -1
$$

Hence,
$$
\boxed{m = 2, \ \ n= -1}
$$

Comment: Do not answer unclear questions.

Comment: OK noted, thanks